make call with pjsip in android application
I am newbie in VOIP and pjsip library in android and I want to make a phone call with pjsua2 library but always I got an error in creating account and adding it to sip.
this is my code to make call
SipProfile.getInstance().makeCall("sip:" + et_dialed_number.getText().toString().trim() + "@" + prefs.getSipServer(), getActivity());

and this is SIPProfile.java class
public class SipProfile {

    private static SipProfile instance = null;
    private MyCall call = null;
    private MyAccount account = null;
    private String lastOnlineStatus = "";
    private int lastStatusCode =0;
    private boolean isInComingCall = false;
    private String balance = "";
    private int coin = 0;
    private String callingNumber = "";
    private String CallInitiatedTime ="";
    private boolean isCallOngoing = false;
    private boolean userNotDisconnectedYet = true;
    private String minInSec = "";

    public String getMinInSec() {
        return minInSec;
    }

    public void setMinInSec(String minInSec) {
        this.minInSec = minInSec;
    }

    public boolean isCallOngoing() {
        return isCallOngoing;
    }

    public void setCallOngoing(boolean callOngoing) {
        isCallOngoing = callOngoing;
    }

    public String getCallingNumber() {
        return callingNumber;
    }

    public void setCallingNumber(String callingNumber) {
        this.callingNumber = callingNumber;
    }

    public MyAccount getAccount() {
        return this.account;
    }

    public void setAccount(MyAccount account) {
        this.account = account;
    }

    public void setCall(MyCall call) {
        this.call = call;
    }

    public MyCall getCall() {
        return call;
    }

    public int getCoin() {
        return coin;
    }

    public static SipProfile getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new SipProfile();
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public String getLastOnlineStatus() {
        return lastOnlineStatus;
    }

    public void setLastOnlineStatus(String lastOnlineStatus) {
        this.lastOnlineStatus = lastOnlineStatus;
    }

    public void makeCall(final String number,final Activity activity){

        Permissions.check(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
                        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},null, null,
                new PermissionHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGranted() {
                        //do your task.
                        try {

                            if (call != null){
                                Toast.makeText(activity, "Call exist",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                return;
                            }
                            if(account == null){
                                Log.i("Account config mohamed","Account is null in sip");
                                Toast.makeText(activity, "Invalid account",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                return;
                            }

                            if (account.getInfo().getRegStatus().swigValue() == SipCallSession.StatusCode.OK) {//
                                isInComingCall = false;
                                setCallingNumber(number);
                                makeCallWithOptions(number);
                                if (!isMyServiceRunning(activity,CallService.class)){
                                    activity.startService(CallService.createIntent(activity));
                                }
                            } else {
                                Log.i("call mohamed",account.getInfo().getRegStatus().swigValue()+"");
                            }
                        }catch(Exception e){

                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDenied(Context context, ArrayList<String> deniedPermissions) {
                        super.onDenied(context, deniedPermissions);
                    }
                });



    }

    public boolean isMyServiceRunning(Context activity,Class<?> serviceClass) {
        android.app.ActivityManager manager = (android.app.ActivityManager)activity. getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (android.app.ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void makeCallWithOptions(String number){

        if(account == null) return;
        call = null;
        MyCall mcall = new MyCall(account, -1);
        CallOpParam prm = new CallOpParam(true);

        if (timerStarted){
            timerHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
            timerStarted = false;
        }
        time_counter = 0;
        CallDuration = "00:00:00";

        try {
            mcall.makeCall(number, prm);
            CallInitiatedTime = getTimeDate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        call = mcall;

    }

    public void showIncomingCall(MyCall call,Service activity){

        try {
            if(this.call != null) return;
            this.call = call;
            this.isInComingCall = true;
            CallInitiatedTime = getTimeDate();
            setCallingNumber(call.getInfo().getRemoteUri());
            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, CallActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            activity.startActivity(intent);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void showCallActivity(Activity activity) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, CallActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }

    public boolean isInComingCall() {
        return isInComingCall;
    }

    public void setInComingCall(boolean inComingCall) {
        isInComingCall = inComingCall;
    }

    public String getStatusText(Activity activity){

        String msg_str="";
        Account account = SipProfile.getInstance().getAccount();
        try {
            int status = account.getInfo().getRegStatus().swigValue();

            if (status == SipCallSession.StatusCode.OK){
                msg_str += activity.getResources().getString(R.string.acct_registered);
            }

            else if (status == SipCallSession.StatusCode.TRYING){
                msg_str += "Trying to register...";
            }

            else if (status == SipCallSession.StatusCode.FORBIDDEN){
                msg_str += activity.getResources().getString(R.string.user_not_found);
            }

            else if (status == SipCallSession.StatusCode.UNAUTHORIZED){
                msg_str += activity.getResources().getString(R.string.wrong_password);
            }

            else if (status == SipCallSession.StatusCode.REQUEST_TIME_OUT){
                msg_str +=activity.getResources().getString(R.string.request_time_out);
            }

            else if (status == SipCallSession.StatusCode.NOT_FOUND){
                msg_str += activity.getResources().getString(R.string.user_not_found);
            }

            else if (status == SipCallSession.StatusCode.NETWORK_UNRECHABLE){
                msg_str += activity.getResources().getString(R.string.check_internet);
            }
            else {
                msg_str += status +" "+ account.getInfo().getRegStatusText();

            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return msg_str;
    }

    public int getStatusColor(Activity activity){

        int color = activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.red_400);
        Account account = SipProfile.getInstance().getAccount();


        try {

            if (account == null) return color;

            if (account.getInfo() == null) return color;

            if(account.getInfo().getRegStatus() == null) return color;

            if(account.getInfo().getRegStatus().swigValue() == 0) return color;


            int status = account.getInfo().getRegStatus().swigValue();
            if (status == SipCallSession.StatusCode.OK){
                color = activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.green_400);
            } else if (status == SipCallSession.StatusCode.FORBIDDEN){
                color = activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.red_400);
            } else if (status == SipCallSession.StatusCode.REQUEST_TIME_OUT){
                color = activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.red_400);
            } else if (status == SipCallSession.StatusCode.NOT_FOUND){
                color = activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.red_400);
            } else if (status == SipCallSession.StatusCode.NETWORK_UNRECHABLE){
                color = activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.red_400);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return color;
    }

    public void setBalance(String bal){
        this.balance = bal;
    }

    public void setCoin(int coin){
        this.coin = coin;
    }


    public String getBalance(){
        return balance;
    }

    public void holdCall() {
        CallOpParam prm = new CallOpParam(true);
        if(call == null) return;
        try {
            call.setHold(prm);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void unHoldCall() {
        CallOpParam prm = new CallOpParam(true);
        if(call == null) return;
        prm.getOpt().setFlag(1);
        try {
            call.reinvite(prm);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void sendDTMF(String key){

        if(this.call == null) return;

        try {
            this.call.dialDtmf(key);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    callDurationListener durationListener;
    private int time_counter = 0;
    private String CallDuration = "00:00:00";
    boolean timerStarted = false;
    private Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            timerStarted = true;
            time_counter++;
            CallDuration = ConvertSecondToHHMMString(time_counter);
            if(durationListener!= null){
                durationListener.UpdateDuration(CallDuration);
            }
            if (timerHandler != null) {

                String timeinsec = minInSec.trim();
                int interval = 1000;
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(timeinsec)){
                    try{
                        interval = Math.round((Float.parseFloat(timeinsec)/60) * 1000);
                        Log.e("inverval",""+interval);
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                timerHandler.postDelayed(runnable, interval);
            }
        }
    };

    public void setDurationListener(callDurationListener listener){
        this.durationListener = listener;
    }
    public void cancelListener(){
        durationListener = null;
    }

    public interface callDurationListener{
        void UpdateDuration(String duration);
    }

     void startTimer(){
        timerHandler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);
    }

     void stopTimer(){
        if (timerStarted){
            timerHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
            timerStarted = false;
        }
        Log.e("Sipprofile","stopTimer");
        time_counter = 0;
        setCallOngoing(false);
        updateCallLog();
        CallDuration = "00:00:00";
        setCallingNumber("");
    }

    private String ConvertSecondToHHMMString(int secondtTime) {

        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        df.setTimeZone(tz);
        String time = df.format(new Date(secondtTime * 1000L));
        return time;

    }


    private String formatPhoneNumber(String phonenumber) {

        Pattern sipUriSpliter = Pattern
                .compile("^(?:\")?([^<\"]*)(?:\")?[ ]*(?:<)?sip(?:s)?:([^@]*)@[^>]*(?:>)?");
        Matcher m = sipUriSpliter.matcher(phonenumber);
        if (m.matches()) {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(m.group(2))) {
                phonenumber = m.group(2);

            } else if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(m.group(1))) {

                phonenumber = m.group(1);// change by zem
            }
        }

        return phonenumber;

    }
    private void updateCallLog() {

        String phonenumber = formatPhoneNumber(getCallingNumber());
        String Duration = CallDuration;
        CallDuration = "00:00:00";

        StoreCallLog newLog = new StoreCallLog();
        StoreContacts contacts = ContactUtils.getContactNameAndPhotoUri(phonenumber);
        DBHandlerCallLog db = new DBHandlerCallLog(Application.getInstance().getApplicationContext());

        if(contacts.getContactName()==null ||contacts.getContactName().equalsIgnoreCase("")){

            newLog.setName(phonenumber);
        }else{
            newLog.setName(contacts.getContactName());
        }

        if(phonenumber.startsWith("000")){
            phonenumber = phonenumber.substring(3);
        }
        newLog.setNumber(phonenumber);
        newLog.setImageUri(contacts.getPhotoUri());
        newLog.setDatetime(CallInitiatedTime);
        newLog.setDuration(Duration);

        if(SipProfile.getInstance().isInComingCall()){

            if(Duration.equalsIgnoreCase("00:00:00")){
                newLog.setCallType("Missed call");
            }else{
                newLog.setCallType("Incoming call");
            }
        }else{
            newLog.setCallType("Dialed call");
        }

        db.add(newLog);
    }

    public String getTimeDate() {

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        String date_time = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
        return date_time;
    }

    public boolean isUserNotDisconnectedYet() {
        return userNotDisconnectedYet;
    }

    public void setUserNotDisconnectedYet(boolean userNotDisconnectedYet) {
        this.userNotDisconnectedYet = userNotDisconnectedYet;
    }

    public  int convertToCoin(String balance){

        try {
            float bal = Float.parseFloat(balance);
            float coin = bal* 1000;

            return Math.round(coin);

        }catch (Exception e){

            return 0;
        }
    }

    public String convertTobalance(String amount){
        try {
            Log.e("amount--",amount);
            double coin = Double.parseDouble(amount);
            Log.e("coin--",""+coin);
            double balance = coin / 1000;
            Log.e("balance--",""+balance);
            return String.valueOf(balance);

        }catch (Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
    }
}

and this always prints in my log message Account is null in sip
and this is MyAccount.java class
public class MyAccount extends Account {
    public ArrayList<MyBuddy> buddyList = new ArrayList<>();
    public AccountConfig cfg;

    public MyAccount(AccountConfig config) {
        super();
        cfg = config;
    }

    public MyBuddy addBuddy(BuddyConfig bud_cfg) {
        MyBuddy bud = new MyBuddy(bud_cfg);
        try {
            bud.create(this, bud_cfg);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            bud.delete();
            bud = null;
        }

        if (bud != null) {
            buddyList.add(bud);
            if (bud_cfg.getSubscribe()) {
                try {
                    bud.subscribePresence(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return bud;
    }

    public void delBuddy(MyBuddy buddy) {
        buddyList.remove(buddy);
        buddy.delete();
    }

    public void delBuddy(int index) {
        MyBuddy bud = buddyList.get(index);
        buddyList.remove(index);
        bud.delete();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRegState(OnRegStateParam prm) {
        MyApp.observer.notifyRegState(prm.getCode(), prm.getReason(), prm.getExpiration());
    }

    @Override
    public void onIncomingCall(OnIncomingCallParam prm) {
        System.out.println("======== Incoming call ======== ");
        MyCall call = new MyCall(this, prm.getCallId());
        MyApp.observer.notifyIncomingCall(call);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInstantMessage(OnInstantMessageParam prm) {
        System.out.println("======== Incoming pager ======== ");
        System.out.println("From     : " + prm.getFromUri());
        System.out.println("To       : " + prm.getToUri());
        System.out.println("Contact  : " + prm.getContactUri());
        System.out.println("Mimetype : " + prm.getContentType());
        System.out.println("Body     : " + prm.getMsgBody());
    }
}

addAcc method
public MyAccount addAcc(AccountConfig cfg) {
        MyAccount acc = new MyAccount(cfg);
        if (acc == null) {
            Log.v("AccountConfig", "Account is null");
            return null;
        }
        try {
            acc.create(cfg);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("AccountConfig", "Failed to add account", e);
            acc = null;
            return null;
        }

        accList.add(acc);
        return acc;
    }

this always print in my log this error message
Failed to add account

java.lang.Exception: Title:       pjsua_acc_add(&pj_acc_cfg, make_default, &id)
Code:        171039
Description: Unknown pjsip error 171039
Location:    ../src/pjsua2/account.cpp:991

    at org.pjsip.pjsua2.pjsua2JNI.Account_create__SWIG_1(Native Method)
    at org.pjsip.pjsua2.Account.create(Account.java:63)
    at app.symlexdialer.vpn.engine.MyApp.addAcc(MyApp.java:360)
    at app.symlexdialer.vpn.engine.SIPService.configureAccount(SIPService.java:202)
    at app.symlexdialer.vpn.engine.SIPService.registerAccount(SIPService.java:151)
    at app.symlexdialer.vpn.engine.SIPService.initPjSip(SIPService.java:94)
    at app.symlexdialer.vpn.engine.SIPService.onCreate(SIPService.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3532)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:199)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1666)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)


I'm stuck in this error for four days ago and can't find any tutorial for that.
so what is my problem ? and how to solve it ?

Please reformat the error message. The stack trace is totally wrong indented so that it is not visible by default.

As an aside I recommend you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for all of your time work. For formatting an amount of time see for example my answer here. Use Duration.ofSeconds() instead of Duration.ofMillis() as in that answer. The SimpleDateFormat class was a notorious troublemaker of a class and has fortunately been outdated for 10 years now.
